# Build heap algorithm(s) on an array.Generate outcomes without brute-forcing

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, heap

The Build-Heap algorithm given in CLRS

```
BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)
1  heap-size[A] ← length[A]
2  for i ← ⌊length[A]/2⌋ downto 1
3       do MAX-HEAPIFY(A, i)
```

It produces only One of several possible cases.Are there other algorithms which would yield a different case than that of the above algorithm.
For input array 
A={4,1,3,2,16,9,10,14,8,7}
Build-Heap produces A={16,14,10,8,7,9,3,2,4,1} which satisfies heap property.
May be this is the most efficient algorithm to build a heap out of an array but there are several other permutations of the array which also have the heap property.
When i generated all permutations of the array and performed a test for heap property.I got 3360 permutations of the array which had the heap property.

```
Count1   16    9    14    4    8    10    3    2    1    7
Count2   16    9    14    4    8    10    3    1    2    7
Count3    16    9    14    4    8    10    2    1    3    7
Count4    16    9    14    4    8    10    2    3    1    7
Count5    16    9    14    4    8    10    7    2    1    3
Count6    16    9    14    4    8    10    7    2    3    1
Count7    16    9    14    4    8    10    7    1    3    2
Count8     16    9    14    4    8    10    7    1    2    3
Count9     16    9    14    4    8    10    7    3    1    2
Count10    16    9    14    4    8    10    7    3    2    1
 ...........................................................

Count3358    16    8    14    7    4    9    10    2    1    3
Count3359    16    8    14    7    4    9    10    3    2    1
Count3360    16    8    14    7    4    9    10    3    1    2
```

So is there a different build-heap algorithm which would give an output which differs from that of the above algorithm or which gives some of the 3360 possible outcomes?

Once we have used the build-heap to get an array which satisfies the heap property.How can we generate maximum number of other cases using this array.We can swap the leaf nodes of the heap to generate some of the cases.Is there any other way to get more possible cases without checking all permutations for heap property test?

Given the range of values in the array and all values being distinct.Can we say anything about the total number of possible cases that will satisfy the heap property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any heap building algorithm will be sensitive to the order in which items are inserted. Even the Build-Heap algorithm will generate a different heap if you give it the same elements, but in a different order.

Remember that when you're building a heap, the partially-built part must maintain the heap property after each insertion. So that's going to limit the different permutations that can be generated by any particular algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Given a heap, it's fairly easy to generate at least some of the permitted permutations.

A node doesn't care about the relative size of its two child nodes. Therefore, you can swap the children of any node, then do a sift-up on the smaller of the two to ensure that the heap property is maintained for that subtree (i.e., if it's smaller than one of its sub-nodes, swap it with that sub-node, and continue doing the same down that path until it gets to a spot where it's larger than either sub-node, or it's moved close enough to the end of the array that it's a leaf node.

Comment: If two non-leaf nodes are swapped wouldn't there be a need to call Heapify().Can u please give an example of what you meant by shift-up?

Comment: @n000b: That's "sift up", not "shift up". I *believe* "sift" is a fairly common term when dealing with a heap. When you add a new item to the end of the heap, you do a "sift down". When (for example, in a heap sort) you put an item at the beginning of the heap, you then do a sift up to get it to were it maintains the heap invariant.